# JavaFX FileChooser open multiple files in order of selection

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I am using a JavaFX FileChooser to open one or two files

```
File file1,file2;
List<File> list = fileChooser.showOpenMultipleDialog(stage);
if (list!=null) {
    file1 = list.get(0);
    if (list.size() > 1)
        file2 = list.get(1);
}
```

But the files in the list will always be sorted alphabetically while I want to open the files in the order they were clicked. Is there a way to achieve this?

In the textfield in the FileChooser, the filepaths are displayed in the order in which they are selected so there seems to be a difference, but the returned list will always be sorted alphabetically.

Edit: The selected files are always ordered by the sorting in the FileChooser. If I set the Windows-ordering to "by date" the files will be returned in that order instead of alphabetical.

Comment: What platform do you use? I tried it on Windows7: when files are multiselected (using Shift or Ctrl) the files in the textfield of the filechooser are already sorted alphabetically. If I change the order manually, they are returned in the order what I set.

Comment: I'm on Win7 Professional. The files in the selected folder are sorted alphabetically in the folder properties.
For me selected files are added at the front as they are selected (with ctrl).
With shift-select all files in between are added at the end in the order in which they are sorted in the folder.